# Laravel updating from 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project in Laravel 5.2 and i'm trying to update it to 5.5. I first started following the official guide to update to 5.3 from 5.2, i did all the steps and my app isn't working properly. When I go to the site, it opens the login but after i enter username and password it looks "loading" but all it do is reload the login page. Checked and re-checked all items from update guide and i don't get how to make it work..

this is my web.php routes file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

Route::get('/', function () {


    if (Auth::user()->isPrestador())
        return redirect('/home');
    elseif (Auth::user()->isAuditor())
        return redirect('/auditor');
    else return view('welcome');

})->middleware('auth')->name('home');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/token', function (){
    return csrf_token();
})->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/ayuda', function (){
    if (Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->isPrestador()){
        return Response::make(file_get_contents('./Manual-prestador-CAD.pdf'), 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => "inline; filename='Manual-prestador-CAD.pdf'"
        ]);
    }
    elseif (Auth::user()->isAuditor())
        return Response::make(file_get_contents('./Manual-auditor-CAD.pdf'), 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => "inline; filename='Manual-auditor-CAD.pdf'"
        ]);
});

Route::get('/auditor/{idEstado?}/{idSolicitud?}', 'AuditorController@index')->where('idSolicitud', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('/auditor/form/{idItem}/{backUrl}', 'AuditorController@auditarForm')->where('idItem', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('/auditor/view/{idItem}/{backUrl}', 'AuditorController@auditarView')->where('idItem', '[0-9]+');
Route::post('/auditor/auditar', 'AuditorController@auditar');

Route::post('/afiliado/estado', 'AfiliadoController@consultarEstadoAfiliado');
Route::post('/prestacion/estado', 'PrestacionController@estado');

//ajax autocomplete
Route::get('/prestacion/codigo', 'PrestacionController@codigo');
Route::get('/prestacion/descripcion', 'PrestacionController@descripcion');
Route::get('/prestacion/view/{idItem}/{backUrl}', 'PrestacionController@viewItem')->where('idItem', '[0-9]+');

Route::post('solicitud/crear', 'SolicitudController@crear');
Route::get('solicitud/{idEstado?}/{idSolicitud?}', 'SolicitudController@index')->where('idSolicitud', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('solicitud/emitir/{idSolicitud}/{backUrl}', 'SolicitudController@emitir')->where('idSolicitud', '[0-9]+');
Route::post('solicitud/imprimir/{backUrl}', 'SolicitudController@imprimir');
```

Comment: After 5.4, there are major changes in framework. So you should read & follow: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade

Comment: I know, but all i did is try to update from 5.2 to 5.3 first, so i didn't face the major changes of 5.4 yet.

Comment: As a sidenote, this is why I hate updating Laravel. Everything points to them adhering to semantic versioning, while under the hood, every minor update breaks functionality on at least 20 levels. Anyway, if you look at the network tab of your inspector, is the page actually reloading?

Comment: If i look at the network tab of the inspector, the page reloads. I tried writing anything in username and password and it works the same, so verification isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the answer to my problem. 
As I use an username for login to my app, i checked LoginController and added "protected $username = 'USERNAME';" just like my controller in 5.2, it didn't help so i keep looking and found that the login didn't work 'cause nobody was returning the username, so i create:

```
public function username()
    {
        return 'USERNAME';
    }
```

inside the LoginController, tried again and it works!
Thanks for the other answers, hope this can help other people.